# How to retrieve information through table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have SQL query that does that I need:

```
SELECT users.FirstName, users.Id FROM `orders` 
INNER JOIN orderrecipients ON orderrecipients.Orders_Id = orders.Id
INNER JOIN users ON users.Id = orderrecipients.Users_Id;
```

I try to use Eloquent model to build query above using `hasManyThrough`:

```
public function OrderRecipients()
{
 return $this->hasManyThrough('App\OrderRecipient', 'App\User', 'Id', 'Orders_Id');
}
```

And using is:

```
$recipients = OrderModel::with("OrderRecipients")->where("User_Id", $userId)->get();
dd($recipients->OrderRecipients()->count());
```

How to build this relation and get data through table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HasManyThrough` is not the best choice here. Use a `BelongsToMany` relationship instead:

```php
public function OrderRecipients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'orderrecipients', 'Orders_Id', 'Users_Id');
}
```